# Facing issue for getting the result of addition of two matrices where matrix elements are being collected from users

Tags: python

Getting elements as input from user and adding the two matrices.

```
 B3=int(input("Enter the number of rows "))
        B4=int(input("Enter the number of columns "))
        Row1=[]
        for i in range(B3):
            m1=[]
            for j in range(B4):
                m1.append(input("num "))
            Row1.append(m1)
    #Printing the first Matrix
        print(Row1)
        print(len(Row1[0]))
        print(len(Row1))
        Row2=[]
        for i in range(B3):
            n1=[]
            for j in range(B4):
                n1.append(input("num "))
            Row2.append(n1)
    #Printing the second Matrix
        print(Row2)
        Result=[]
        for i in range(len(Row1)):
            for j in range(len(Row1[0])):
                Result[i][j]=Row1[i][j]+Row2[i][j]
    #Printing the addition result of the two matrices
        for r in result:
           print(r)
#

#getting elements as input from user and adding the two matrices.    
#B3 and B4 are the rows and columns of the each matrix 
        B3=int(input("Enter the number of rows "))
        B4=int(input("Enter the number of columns "))
        Row1=[]
        for i in range(B3):
            m1=[]
            for j in range(B4):
                m1.append(input("num "))
            Row1.append(m1)
    #Printing the first Matrix
        print(Row1)
        print(len(Row1[0]))
        print(len(Row1))
        Row2=[]
        for i in range(B3):
            n1=[]
            for j in range(B4):
                n1.append(input("num "))
            Row2.append(n1)
    #Printing the second Matrix
        print(Row2)
        Result=[]
        for i in range(len(Row1)):
            for j in range(len(Row1[0])):
                Result[i][j]=Row1[i][j]+Row2[i][j]
    #Printing the addition result of the two matrices
        for r in result:
           print(r)
```

I am getting error as IndexError: list index out of range. Please help to resolve this issue. I want to add elements to the matrices as input from user and then want to print the addition of the two matrices. I am getting error in the block of code for addition of two matrices.

Answer (score 0):

#### Index out of range error

Your error is in the line `Result[i][j]=Row1[i][j]+Row2[i][j]`. Let's see:

```
Result=[]
for i in range(len(Row1)):
    for j in range(len(Row1[0])):
        Result[i][j]=Row1[i][j]+Row2[i][j]
```

`Result` is an empty list. When you try to access it (`Result[i][j]`) the indexes are out of range.

The correct way to do this is:

```
Result=[]
for i in range(len(Row1)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(Row1[0])):
         row.append(Row1[i][j]+Row2[i][j])
    Result.append(row)
```

The same trick that you have done in other parts of your code.

#### Minor things

You also have `for r in result:` which should be `for r in Result:` (capital letter, you defined the name like this before).

Finally, you never converted the strings to numbers. The sum operator is just concatenating strings, so you have `'1' + '1' = '11'` instead of `1 + 1 = 2`. To fix this you need to convert all the entries like

```
m1.append(input("num "))
```

into:

```
m1.append(int(input("num ")))
```

if you want to work with integers, or:

```
m1.append(float(input("num ")))
```

to allow floating numbers.